# ListObjectsV2 access denied Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm trying to list all objects in a bucket under a prefix with the following code in java:

```
ListObjectsV2Request request =
      new ListObjectsV2Request()
          .withBucketName(bucketName)
          .withDelimiter("/")
          .withPrefix(prefix)
          .withMaxKeys(2);
  ListObjectsV2Result result;
  do {
    result = s3Client.listObjectsV2(req);
    log.info("Results size is : " + result.getObjectSummaries().size());
```

The s3client is set up correctly because I can upload, delete, etc. I only have a problem listing objects. I receive access denied if I don't provide a prefix, but if I provide a prefix I receive an empty response. I tested `aws s3 ls` to see if I had permissions and I'm able to print the whole bucket out that way. Any ideas for next steps for debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by sshing into instance and comparing the output of aws s3 ls & s3api. Had forgotten mandatory prefix and delimiter.